# Norm definition for arbitrary spin fields in AdS

Tags: ads-cft, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In AdS/CFT one usually hears of normalizable and non-normalizable modes regarding the independent solutions for the different fields. I've found that the "natural" definition of the norm in the case of the scalar field is given by

$-i \int \sqrt{-g} (\phi^* \partial^t \phi-\phi \partial^t \phi ^*) $

Where the integral is along an equal-time slice. I have two questions:
Why is that the appropriated definition of norm for a scalar field in a curved spacetime? 
How does this generalize to higher spin fields?